# I have an error on my stack using a linked list. Unable to print loop of numbers. (C++)

Tags: c++, struct, stack

$ I have the following error: 
    44 E:\Assignment 2.cpp no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout <  (&number)->newstack::push(x)'

$ I'm using a linked list to put numbers in a class stack that contains a struct. The stack that contains these numbers are printed out. But the error will not allow me to print them out.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int itemType;


 class newstack
  {

private:
  Using a struct of nodes which contains a item and pointer to the next node.

  struct node  
  {

        itemType item;
    node *next;
  };

   node *top;  //pointer to the top node.
 public:

  void push(itemType newItem); //adds items to newstack

   };




  int main()

  { 
     newstack number; 
      int x;

      cout<< "Number Stack" <<endl;

     for (x=0;x<=9;x++) 

     cout<<(number).push(x)<<endl;  //ERROR LINE
     //Takes 9 integers and adds them to the stack by printing them out.
     return 0;

   }


  void newstack::push(itemType newItem)
  // Precondition: Stack is empty.
  //Postcondition: Stack contains a itemType  at the top and list or stack implements     by 1.
   {  
             if(top!=NULL)    
     node *newTop;
             newTop=new node;
    (*newTop).item=newItem;
         (*newTop).next=top;
          top=newTop;

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

IN your push() function you are returning Void.
Yet you try and write the value the function returns
to the command prompt - either change your push function
to return a value or cout << stack.pop();

Further On:
You need to overload the << operator for your newstack class to be able to write something like:

```
newstack obj;
cout<<obj;
```

`<<` is overloaded for only built-in data types not custom class types.

You need to overload it something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const newstack& obj);
```

Comment: While your initial answer is good, one wonders how `pop` is supposed to work, given that it doesn't even exist...

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit with additional information,Feel free to remove it if you find it not useful.

Comment: @Als - Thanks i really don't mind... i welcome it. Thankyou See below for a complete linkedlist

Comment: @ Kereek SB ** I wrote my pop() function but the only problem was my push(). But now i know i can use my pop() function to print  **

Comment: @Aiden Strydom, @ Als ** Thanks I see what i can do now**

Comment: quick fix - change  void newstack::push(itemType newItem)
to  itemType newstack::push(itemType newItem)
and at the end of the function return newItem

Answer (score 1):

```
cout<<(number).push(x)<<endl;
```

First, you don't need the `()` around `number`

```
cout << number.push(x) << endl;
```

That still won't work, because `newstack::push` returns `void`.

Either change `newstack::push` to return the value added, or print the number in a separate step.

Answer (score 1):

See The Following

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Defenitions

template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T DataMember;
    Node* Next;
};

template <class T>
class NCA
{
    public:
        NCA();
        ~NCA();
        void push(T);
        T pop();
        void print();
        void Clear();
    private:
        Node<T>* Head;
        void* operator new(unsigned int);
};

//Imp.

template <class T>
NCA<T>::NCA()
{
    Head = NULL;
}

template <class T>
NCA<T>::~NCA()
{
    Clear();
}

template <class T>
void NCA<T>::push(T value)
{
    Node<T>* Temp = new Node<T>;

    Temp->DataMember = value;
    Temp->Next = Head;
    Head = Temp;
}

template <class T>
T NCA<T>::pop()
{
    Node<T>* n;
    T i;
    n = Head->Next;
    i = Head->DataMember;
    delete Head;
    Head = n;
    return i;
}

template <class T>
void NCA<T>::print()
{
    Node<T>* MockHead = Head;

    while (MockHead != NULL)
    {
        cout << MockHead->DataMember;
        MockHead = MockHead->Next;
    }
}

template <class T>
void NCA<T>::Clear()
{
    while(Head != NULL)
        pop();
}

//Main Execution

int main()
{
    NCA<char> Array;
    Array.push('c');
    cout << Array.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note The Push function - it returns a value from the stack/list
Ps. NCA stands for non-contiguous array

Answer (score 0):

You haven't override the operator << for your newstack which is causing the error. If you printed x, then did the push afterwards, you wouldn't receive an error. If you want cout to be able to print your stack you need to define HOW the << operator works.

The real problem here is how you're expecting your code to work. First, push shouldn't return a value to begin with, that's not how a stack works. You could implement pop which would pop off and return the top value of the stack, however then you're losing that value. You need to implement peek.  Because this is homework I wont give you a direct answer on how to write peek but this should be a better way of executing your code.

```
for (x=0; x<=9; x++)
{
    number.push(x);
    cout << number.peek() << endl;
}
```

Comment: **Thanks. oh right. push() is a void. So i have to write another function to print out the values.**